# Destructure, change name and set type

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I want to do **destructuring** (extract `row` from `sel`), change destructured variable **name** (from `row` to `tableRow`), and **type** this new variable (it's a `number`), all at once:

```
const { row: tableRow }: { row: number } = sel; // sel = { row: 5 }
```

So I can later use `tableRow` in my code:

```
console.log(tableRow); // will output number 5
```

The code works, but TSLint throws this error:

```
ERROR: variable 'row' used before declaration.
```

How can I improve type syntax on that destructuring + name change + typing?

Comment: This is an open bug for Tslint related to destructuring . check this https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2551

Comment: an work around could be to set the key `"no-use-before-declare": false` in tslint.json